# raspbian does not boot on QEMU

Tags: kernel, qemu

I am trying to emulate raspbian on windows 10 64 bit. My start.bat is

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw -drive "file=2017-08-16-raspbian-stretch.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw" -redir tcp:2222::22
```

I also edit the rules file

```
KERNEL=="sda", SYMLINK+="mmcblk0"
KERNEL=="sda?", SYMLINK+="mmcblk0p%n"
KERNEL=="sda2", SYMLINK+="root"
```

but when I run start.bat from cmd prompt, I see this:

[image: qemu logs]

The kernel boots up but I didn't get anything started after that. What's wrong? Is it a kernel mismatch with the latest release of Raspbian?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it will work. I am doing the same thing as you.

qemu-system-arm.exe -M versatilepb -cpu arm1176 -hda 2017-08-16-raspbian-stretch.img -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie -m 256 -append "root=/dev/sda2"